# I 'm storring a value in localstorage and trying to use it in an if statement but i get only null, i have stringify the value too

Tags: javascript, jquery, local-storage

This is where I set the value to the localstorage. I get the 
data-rel after click and pass it to the localstorage stringified.

```
var selectedClass = "";
var firstClass = "";
$(".months a").click(function(){
  firstClass = $(this).attr("data-rel");
  localStorage.setItem("firstClass ", JSON.stringify(firstClass) );
});
```

This is where I get the value back from the localstorage.

```
var check = "";
var test2 = localStorage.getItem("firstClass");
check = JSON.parse(test2);
```

And here is when I try to use it but it returns always null so my script
never runs else.

```
if (check === null) {
selectedClass = "";
    $(".fil-cat").click(function(){ 
        selectedClass = $(this).attr("data-rel"); 
     $("#produstswide").fadeTo(100, 0.1);
        $("#produstswide div.fluid-
conteiner").not("."+selectedClass).fadeOut().removeClass('scale-anm');
    setTimeout(function() {
      $("."+selectedClass).fadeIn().addClass('scale-anm');
      $("#produstswide").fadeTo(300, 1);
    }, 300); 

    });
} else {
    selectedClass = check;
     $("#produstswide").fadeTo(100, 0.1);
        $("#produstswide div.fluid-
conteiner").not("."+selectedClass).fadeOut().removeClass('scale-anm');
    setTimeout(function() {
      $("."+selectedClass).fadeIn().addClass('scale-anm');
      $("#produstswide").fadeTo(300, 1);
    }, 300); 
    localStorage.clear();
}
```

Comment: Have you tried consoling `test2` after calling `getItem` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a white space in the key string that you use to set the value

```
localStorage.setItem("firstClass ", JSON.stringify(firstClass) );
```

Try removing it

```
localStorage.setItem("firstClass", JSON.stringify(firstClass) );
```

Comment: If you were here I would kiss you!!!!!!!! Thank you, I was looking at the code for a few hours and I just couldn' t see it.